# Адаптивная Верстка, что да как

Tags: css

Я вот потихоньку вливаюсь в сферу фронтед 
у меня возникла проблема с адаптивной версткой (честно вообще ее не понимаю, как не пытался в голову ничего не приходит) есть макет там 4 заданной ширины 320, 768, 1024, 1280 мне почему то говорят ставь ширину 1440  и от него будешь отталкиваться к мелким 
мне нужно понять, как сделать так чтобы при сжатии страницы это все адаптивно выглядело 
Я так понял там нет фиксированных величин в Px а в %

Comment: надо почитать основы - здесь как бы помогают а не обучают основам

Comment: Во первых, кто тебе говорит ставить 1440? Во вторых, если тебе нужно 4 заданные версии, то делать 4 медиазапросы под каждую ширину. Ну и лучше, конечно, сначала изучить основы адаптивной верстки, без этого никуда

Comment: @vantal не вежливо ТЫ'кать  тому кого не знаешь

Comment: в том то и дело я даже основ понять не могу
адаптивная, отзывчивая, резиновая все это в перемешку и не знаю , что да как

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/content/rezinovyy-dizayn-dvukhkolonnyy-maket  читайте применяйте

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/content/osnovy-verstki